# Angularjs ng-repeat doesn't work as expected

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an Angularjs controller(Angularjs 1.5.6) which calls a function from a python script, which returns an array of elements. I am trying to do an `ng-repeat` so that they appear in the table but for some reason, it doesn't show the elements of the array.

The 'Go' button in the html template triggers the function `getSID` which makes an HTTP call to a python script that returns an array. At the same time, the function also sets the scope, `showval` to true such that the table in the html appears only after the button is clicked.

```
<script>
    angular.module('navigator', [])
        .controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $http) {   
        $scope.getSid = function (sid) {
        console.log(sid);           
            $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/getMachine',
                    data: {sid:$scope.sid}
                    }).then(function(response) {
                    $scope.machines = [];
                    var object1 = response.data;
                    $scope.machines.push(object1);                      

                    //console.log(object1);
                    console.log($scope.machines);
                    $scope.showval = true;

                    }, function(error) {
                      console.log("hello");
                      console.log(error);
                    });
            };
        })
```

HTML code:

```
 <div class="input-group mb-3 input-group-lg">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text">Enter the SID</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="sid">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" ng-click="getSid(sid)" ng-model="show" >
    GO!
  </button>
</div>
<div ng-show="showval">
<table class="table table-dark" >
<thead>
<tr>
  <th scope="col">SID</th>
  <th scope="col">Cluster</th>
  <th scope="col">Node</th>
  <th scope="col">Physical ip</th>
  <th scope="col">Logical ip</th>
  <th scope="col">Logical Host</th>
  <th scope="col">Physical Host</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="item in machines">

  <td>{{item}}</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I googled `ng-repeat` and so several examples in plunker and I am following the same code but my code doesn't seem to work. Would be grateful for any assistance. Thanks for your time.

Comment: it's `ng-repeat="item in machines track by $index"` *

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console? Also you are repeat over an array of objects, have you tried {{ item.field }}? You maybe rendering empty <tr> elements, have a look at your dom using dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

Your need to enclose track by $index within quotes as well,

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in machines track by $index">
```

Comment: Thanks Sajeetharan. That was a typo. The table doesn't update still. I tried the $scope.$apply but that doesn't work either.

Comment: @AjRev you should directly assign it without pushing $scope.machines = response.data

Comment: That didn't work either. Seems more like an issue with ng-repeat itself. I'm able to see the array elements in the console but ng-repeat is not able to read the array

Comment: Can you post the array

Comment: 0
:
(7) ["SCM", "cluster1", "node1", "10.10.10.10", "10.10.10.11, "lscmhost", "pscmhost"]

Answer (score 0):

Guilty of not posting the complete details. I was working with python flask and realized that the conflict is due to Jinja2.

I had to use the {%raw} {%end raw} so that Jinja2 processes it as an html.
More details in this [Link](https://realpython.com/flask-by-example-updating-the-ui/)

Now my code looks like this and ng-repeat is working.

```
{% raw %} 
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="item in machines" >

  <td>{{item}}</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
{% endraw %}
```